# Share data between cron-job and webserver executed PHP scripts

Tags: php, cron, data-sharing

The one below is a common way how a *master* and a *child* script do data sharing:

> cron job -- schedule --> master script
>
> HTTP request -- trigger --> child script
>
> master script --> [database] <-- child script

But is it possible to them to share the data using any of these below, instead of the database?

- `global` variable
- system storage
- session storage
- memcache / apc / any other thing like these

Comment: Sockets are the simplest way to do this. Have you master script create a listening socket, and your child script connect to it, then you have bi-directional communication between the two.

Comment: Session will be stored in browser, so it can't be used when the cron will be executed on the server.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de It is possible, if you know the session ID, to read the data from the session file and call `unserialize()` on it to get the data. It doesn't come recommended though...

Comment: @DaveRandom: Why can't you simply set the SID to resume the session manually?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Apparently you can. For some reason I had it set in my head that `session_start()` was not available in the CLI, but I have just tried it and it is.

Comment: @DaveRandom I just tried to run a script in CLI and another one in my browser with same `session_save_path('/tmp'); session_id('same');` and the web page has Undefined variable for my `$_SESSION['config']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. global variable - **no**
2. system storage *(from comments: this is command line)* - **no** because that would involve one launching the other, and still be one-way...
3. session storage - **yes**, using *named session*, but this will resort to *files* by default (can be configured to use **shm** and then in-memory...)
4. [`memcached`](http://php.net/memcahched) - **yes**
5. [`apc`](http://php.net/apc) - **yes**, but will require explicit configuration to enable in *cli* sapi
6. files - **yes**. And to speed things up, you can use `ramfs` to store files in an in-memory filesystem.
7. sockets - **yes** (make one of the a listener and connect from another)
8. database - **yes** (why not, actually?)

In case i left anything out, you can search for *php interprocess communication*

Comment: @zerkms actually, it should also be **yes**, though it will require explicit configuration to enable it in *cli*. updating, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. not possible
2. what do you mean with system storage?
3. not possible
4. memcach:would be no problem if both applications somehow know the key to the value, apc: not possible

Comment: 5. files ... simple and obvious ;)

Comment: thanx. but i prefer memory based

Comment: @Jerinho "data set via command line" - that is one way communication and only possible if one launches the other

Comment: files can also be memory based. use `ramfs`

Comment: by the way... #3 IS possible - using named session (but that also resorts to files by default, so whats the gain)

Comment: @Jerinho you create virtual filesystem that actually resides in RAM (hence `ramfs`), and for all purposes of handling - what you place there is files... but as soon as you unmount that filesystem, they go void

Answer (score 1):

The only way left is fs. Either socket as DaveRandom suggests, or a simple file.

Why don't you want to use the database? What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: i prefer memory while it is possible

Comment: just a simple web based game engine

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can connect to MySQL servers from cron-job (`php-cli`) executed scripts just like how you can from the webserver, assuming that the `php.ini` for command-line has the database library loaded.

If you don't want to use database, you can either set up sockets or use temporary passthrough files. But using the database would be the most efficient and tidy way.

Answer (score 1):

I second a file solution:

- It's simple to code/understand/maintain
- It's crash foolproof, you will not loose content when there is a problem.
- It's protected against concurrents writes
- It's as fast as memory if your OS decides it needs to be cached for frequent access.
  (Usually it's simpler/safer/faster to not try to replace OS optimisation.)